# How to save session in mvc3 on blocked cookies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my mvc3 application i save data of each user to session.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = "Jon";
```

The problem is in Safari browser.
The default settings is : "block cookies from third parties and advertisers". So session is not saved. I found solution :

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1,
                "currentUser",
                DateTime.Now,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                false,
                null);

                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);

                this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But this solution work only on localhost, is not work on server...
Is anybody have alternative solution for this problem? Or can explain why is my solution not working on server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Domain property of your cookie to exactly match the name of the domain your work server is in, like this:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie(...
cookie.Domain = "Microsoft.com";
```

Once you do it, your cookie is a first-party cookie (as opposed to being a third-party one).